# Week 1 in SQL for SAS environment

Tags: sql, sas

I am working with SQL in SAS environment.  When I want to extract the 1st week of 2024 as a Week 1 of the year, using this query it puts as Week 0.

```
WEEK(datepart(SOME_DATE)) AS Week
```

So the week 01/01/2024 - 08/01/2024 is placed as **Week 0**, not **1**.

*SOME_DATE* variable has a format **Datetime20**.

Comment: I don't know if i am missing something cant you just add one to it. WEEK(datepart(SOME_DATE))+1 AS Week

Comment: As a suggestion its worth including which RDBMS you are using and the version. Certainly when Itested the on MS SQL Server (changing the syntax to work) I got 1. So the answer someone might give will depend on what you are using.

Comment: I am using Oracle Database.

Answer (score 3):

Solved:

I have placed **"v"** as a second parameter to WEEK function and everything is aligned now:

```
WEEK(datepart(SOME_DATE), "v") AS Week
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the definition of the WEEK() function to see what options it supports.  The default is to use the U method which counts weeks from Sunday and the first Sunday in 2024 is the 7th of January.

Let's try some example dates with all three options.

```
data test;
  input date :date.;
  format date date9.;
  u=week(date,'u');
  v=week(date,'v');
  w=week(date,'w');
cards;
01JAN2024
07JAN2024
08JAN2024
01AUG2024
;
```

Result

```
Obs         date     u     v     w

 1     01JAN2024     0     1     1
 2     07JAN2024     1     1     1
 3     08JAN2024     1     2     2
 4     01AUG2024    30    31    31
```

PS Displaying dates in MDY or DMY order will confuse half of your audience.  Is 8/1/2024 the eighth of January or August first?